# Honda Civic 08 - AC control and possible electrical problem

Tags: honda, ac, civic

When I started messing around with this the AC worked sometimes but not others and realizing that the engine fan wasn't turning on. Replacing the thermostat fixed this and the car doesn't run hot anymore. At this point I believe there were three buttons with no backlight in the climate control panel.

Now there's a whole row that's out, and everything that I've been able to test is behaving like the AC system is unaware of the buttons being pushed.
- The fans don't come on with Max AC
- the computer isn't enabling the system by grounding the control signal to the clutch relay

Things that aren't wrong with it:
- the clutch engages if given power
- the lights on the AC and Max AC buttons toggle appropriately 
- the system runs the self-check with no errors
- the 4 pin relays all work, ditto fuses
- there's charge in the system and the voltage reading at the sensor is appropriate
- the compressor works and gets cold 
- cabin filter wasn't clogged

Unknown
 - I'm not sure about the fan speed relay
 - I replaced / cleared rust from a few spots and was in general pretty shocked to see how much rust was in there

At this point my guess is that the button is not really talking to the rest of the car, but I'm not sure where to check the signal at. I'd like to avoid taking the whole console off.

Is there somewhere else I can make sure it's signalling correctly from the button to the computer? Is there something I'm skipping here?

Comment: Have you check the fuses related to the AC?

Comment: I've checked all the fuses. Unless there's one in the climate control console?